# NSCollectionView crashes when creating items

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

My `NSCollectionView` crashes when calling `makeItem(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath)`. `numberOfItemsInSection` returns the correct value. If I call `makeItem...` in `viewDidLoad` rather than in `itemForRepresentedObject` I see an error indicating that the indexPath is out of bounds. How can this be?

The collection view loads like this:

```
class TagCollectionViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDataSource {

  fileprivate static let itemIdentifier = "TagItem"

  @IBOutlet var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
  fileprivate var tags = List<Tag>.init()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "TagCollectionViewItem", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: TagCollectionViewController.itemIdentifier)

    collectionView.dataSource = self
}
```

(The List collection is a Realm class)

During `viewWillAppear()` the tags collection is populated from a ReSwift state:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
  for image in mainStore.state.selectedImages {
    for tag in image.tags {
      tags.append(tag)
    }
  }

  super.viewWillAppear()
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it.

When I created the .xib for the item I added an `NSCollectionViewItem` object but didn't wire up the view to my custom view.

[image]

To recap, for anyone who gets caught out by this, the steps to creating a `NSCollectionViewItem` are:

1. Create the nib and configure your views
2. Add an `NSCollectionViewItem` object to your nib
3. Wire up your view (and any other views) to the object
4. Register the nib with the collectionView in your view controller